# PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer not loading programmatically

Tags: spring, spring-3

I have a custom ApplicationContext class where I'm trying to programmatically load a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, then use the placeholders in my XML config file.

I've tried three different approaches so far, and each time I get an error like this:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named '${domain}.testId' is defined
```

What I am doing wrong?

**Context class**

```
public class MyApplicationContext extends GenericApplicationContext {
    public MyApplicationContext (String... locations) throws IOException {

        // method one
        ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner scanner = new ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner(this);
        scanner.scan("com.my.package");

        // method two
        new MyPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer().postProcessBeanFactory(getBeanFactory());

        // method three
        getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("propertyPlaceholderConfigurer", new MyPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer());

        // load XML config files
        XmlBeanDefinitionReader xmlReader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(this);
        for (String location : locations) {
            xmlReader.loadBeanDefinitions(location);
        }
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="test.testId" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="this is the test value" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="prod.testId" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="this is the prod value" />
    </bean>

    <alias name="${domain}.testId" alias="testId" />

</beans>
```

**Usage**

```
MyApplicationContext context = new MyApplicationContext(
    new String[] { "test.xml" });
Assert.assertEquals("this is the test value", context.getBean("testId"));
```

Comment: Why do you need a custom context for including a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` even your own custom one?

Comment: My context class also does package scanning and logging initialization.  I just didn't include that extra stuff in my example code.  I'm pretty new to Spring, but it seems like a reasonable place to include all that stuff.  Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate the answers on how to define the bean, but it turns out the problem was much simpler.  I was loading the bean just fine, but I wasn't properly initializing my context after loading all the beans.  A simple call to refresh() did the trick.

```
MyApplicationContext context = new MyApplicationContext(
    new String[] { "test.xml" });

context.refresh();   // this runs BeanFactoryPostProcessors like 
                     // MyPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, among other things

Assert.assertEquals("this is the test value", context.getBean("testId"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is standard way how make your properties accessible in configuration file.

```
<util:list id="locations">
    <value>classpath:appconfig.properties</value>
    <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
</util:list>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      p:ignoreResourceNotFound="true"
      p:locations-ref="locations" />

<!-- bean that uses properties -->
<bean id="dataSource"
      class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
      p:driverClass="${jdbc.driver}"
      p:jdbcUrl="${jdbc.url}"
      p:user="${jdbc.user}"
      p:password="${jdbc.pw}"
      p:initialPoolSize="5"
      p:minPoolSize="5"
      p:maxPoolSize="50"
      p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="5" />
```

Another quite useful way how to "inject" properties in your configuration file on ANY place is using maven: you use same syntax `${property-name}` but values are supplied earlier during maven build process - this is relevant part of maven configuration:

```
<properties>
<jdbc.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dummyuserdb</jdbc.url>
<jdbc.user>root</jdbc.user>
<jdbc.pw>admin</jdbc.pw>
</properties>
```

and you have to include your spring's configuration directory in maven filtered resources:

```
<build>
    <resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-config</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
</resources>
```

Or if you prefer java configuration:

```
 @Configuration
 @PropertySource(value = "config/jdbc.properties")
 public class BaseWebConfig {

    @Autowired Environment env;

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean() {
       MyBean myBean = new MyBean();
       String propertyValue = env.getProperty("my-property-name");
       // do something with myBean and propertyValue
       return myBean;
    }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use your own custom `MyPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` (assuming it extends `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`, then all you need to do is to put it as a `bean` in your application context, it'll do all the rest for you:

```
<bean class="my.pkg.MyPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" />
```

Comment: Does this require a configuration file, then?  It can't be done in code?

Comment: You've already got a configuration XML (`test.xml`), that's where it would go.

Comment: Why is using a configuration XML better or different than scanning the bean in as a component?  My system is a bit more complex than just the three files shown in my question, and I was hoping for a better solution than adding it to my main XML or creating a second one.

Comment: In my view, creating your own application context is not a such good idea because there are different types of context (e.g. `XmlWebApplicationContext` or `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`), so you'd have to subclass them all.

Comment: That's reasonable, although for my app I could just pick a base class and stick with it (GenericApplicationContext, in my case).  I'm not building a library.  But it's good to know that the preferred way is not to subclass.  I'll consider fixing that soon.