# Spring: Using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer support outside of application context

Tags: java, spring

My applications requirements mean that I need to create application beans manually at runtime and then add them to the application context.

These beans belong to third party libraries so I cannot modify them e.g. a `TibjmsConnectionFactory`

So my factory class that creates these beans needs to be provided with a `Properties` object that will set username, password, connectionTimeouts etc

Ideally I'd like to use `Spring`'s property support so I do not need to convert Strings to Integers etc

Also, the `Properties` provided to my factory class will not be the same Properties used for by the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` in my overall `ApplicationContext`

How do I achieve this, or is it even possible?

```
public class MyCustomFactoryStrategy  {
    @Override
    public TibjmsConnectionFactory create(Properties properties) {
        TibjmsConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new TibjmsConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setServerUrl(properties.getProperty("emsServerUrl")); // this is a string
        connectionFactory.setConnAttemptCount(new Integer(properties.getProperty("connAttemptCount"))); // this is an integer
        ...
        return connectionFactory;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in this post. I think it might be what you need.

[[PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer not loading programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075434/propertyplaceholderconfigurer-not-loading-programmatically][1])

[1]:

Comment: So the suggestion here is to create a custom application context in place of my factory above, and then once I've the bean initialized I can take it from that application context and add to my main one?

Comment: Yes there are two things to be done here. First thing is to obtain a handle of your context so that you are able to configure it programmatically. The second point is to initialize PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer so that you are able to pass system properties from outside the application.